# What is wrong with def f=x:Int->List(x-1,x,x+1) in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

Hi I do not quite follow why this definition in Scala does not work.

```
scala> def f=x:Int->List(x-1,x,x+1)
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '(' found.
       def f=x:Int->List(x-1,x,x+1)
                        ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two immediate problems:

1. `->` should be `=>`
2. `x:Int` should be `(x:Int)`

So this works:

```
def f = (x: Int) => List(x - 1, x, x + 1)
```

However this is defining a function that returns a function, which is probably not what is intended. So instead try

```
val f = (x: Int) => List(x - 1, x, x + 1)
```

or

```
def f(x: Int) = List(x - 1, x, x + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is syntactically incorrect: I think what you want is:

```
def f(x: Int):List[Int] = List(x-1,x,x+1)
```

First, A function type is defined with `=>`, not `->`, maybe you come from `haskell`, so for example, a function with `Int` param and that returns a `List[Int]` will have the type `Int => List[Int]`